# How to use normal displacement instead of vector displacement in shader editor (2.8)

Tags: node-editor, displacement

I am creating a material in 2.8, and am using real displacement in the shader, but how do I use normal displacement, rather than vector? The reason is that when I use a black/white heightmap,  the geometry displaces in a single direction, not in the direction of the geometry's faces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out: Use heightmap for the height value in a displacement node, use the output of the displacement node as displacement.